# google adsense mobile view

Tags: mobile, adsense, ads

According to my client's research referenced here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354762?hl=en#n2 you are only allowed one ad for Google on mobile pages.

Also in Google rules is stated that ads may not be obscured, and hence it flows that they cannot be hidden.

The problem that I am currently sitting is that the site is a single site for both desktop and mobile views, and that to the best of my knowledge, I would have to hide content on client-side to ensure that only one ad is shown on the mobile view, as opposed to the three on the desktop view.

How do I achieve 3 ads on a desktop view and only one on the mobile view for a single site, without hiding the extra 2 ads on mobile view? Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress then you can use "Google Publisher plugins (https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-publisher/) .

Actually it automatically adjust ads size according to screen whatever use mobile or pc